# Razor month dropdown to select current month

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've seen that there are plenty of ways to create a dropdown in razor that populates with a range of months and years. But, is there a lightweight way to autoselect the current month in that dropdown without resorting to js/jquery post page render? Let's say it's for a credit card form and I want to make sure that the dropdown autoselects the current month.

In case you need code, here's what I'm working with:

```
@{
   int[] months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).ToArray();
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ExpirationMonth, 
                     months.Select(x => 
                          new SelectListItem { 
                            Text = x.ToString(), 
                            Value = x.ToString()
                          }
                     ))
```

Comment: `new SelectListItem { ..., Selected = x == DateTime.Today.Month }`?

Comment: Tried it. Makes sense it might work but it doesn't :(

Comment: Well, what's in `x.ExpirationMonth`? May want to assign that a default value of the current month, too. (I assumed it was nullable, but that may be the issue).

Comment: Int, not nullable. Just a column in an EF model for a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@{
    int[] months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).ToArray();
    int curMonth = DateTime.Today.Month;
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ExpirationMonth, months.Select(x => 
    new SelectListItem {
        Text = x.ToString(),
        Value = x.ToString(),
        Selected = (x == curMonth)
    }
))
```

Check against `DateTime.Today.Month` in your `.Select()` when you build the list (and populate the [`Selected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.selected%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) property).

Comment: I want that to be the answer but it's not doing for the dropdown. It's not rendering a selected option for any of the items, true OR false.

Comment: @MetalPhoenix: FWIW, if I specify `model.ExpirationMonth = DateTime.Today.Month` then return `View(model)` in my action, I get "12" selected.

Comment: Yeah, seems to work that way too but sure that I want to do that. The page already has a model being passed in that is far more complex than it has any right to be (inherited code). I'll mark yours as the answer even though I can't use (right now). Thanks!

Comment: @MetalPhoenix: I also looked into it after our discussion and found it's because of the `GetSelectListWithDefaultValue` method in System.Web.Mvc. When populating the select list, the `Selected = item.Value != null ? set.Contains(item.Value) : set.Contains(item.Text);` where `set = new Object[]{ x.ExpirationMonth }` (essentially) so it ignores pre-defined `Selected` values. Makes sense that the model should be the driving value though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do achieve that using simple loop and logic:

```
<select class="combo">
    @{
        var currnt = DateTime.Now.Month;
        var counter = currnt;
        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
        {
            if (counter > 12)
            {
                counter = 1;
            }
            // option 1 - month number:
            <option>@counter</option>
            // option 2 - month name:
            // <option>@DivisionPortal.Models.Helpers.TimeHelpers.GetMonthName((byte)counter)</option>
            counter++;
        }
    }
</select>
```

If someone need to use the month name insted of the number this is how 
`DivisionPortal.Models.Helpers.TimeHelpers.GetMonthName()` looks like:

```
public static string GetMonthName(byte m)
{
    string smonth = null;

    switch (m)
    {
        case 1:
            {
                smonth = "JAN";
                break;
            }

        case 2:
            {
                smonth = "FEB";
                break;
            }

        case 3:
            {
                smonth = "MAR";
                break;
            }

        case 4:
            {
                smonth = "APR";
                break;
            }

        case 5:
            {
                smonth = "MAI";
                break;
            }

        case 6:
            {
                smonth = "JUN";
                break;
            }

        case 7:
            {
                smonth = "JUL";
                break;
            }

        case 8:
            {
                smonth = "AUG";
                break;
            }

        case 9:
            {
                smonth = "SEP";
                break;
            }

        case 10:
            {
                smonth = "OCT";
                break;
            }

        case 11:
            {
                smonth = "NOV";
                break;
            }

        case 12:
            {
                smonth = "DEC";
                break;
            }
    }

    return smonth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@{

string curMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");

}
```

Get the current month like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedMonth, Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(x) }), curMonth, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Create a dropdown with the option label set to curMonth and SelectedMonth a string in your model/viewModel.